# Is there an alternative for the unsupported CQL IN operator in Amazon Keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

For Increasing data fetch performance, we are migrating to amazon keyspace from some relation tables.

But While using amazon keyspace having multiple problems due to lack of cql support

**Since it doesn't have IN clause support, Is there any alternative or workaround for this?**

Also it doesn't support secondary index creation, Is there work around to query data on partitioned key and other column (Note: other column can't be a clustered key, they can be null as well)

If above can't be resolve in amazon keyspace,
**Is it still considered a good practice to use amazon keyspace for cassandra db, as it's doesn't have support in many aspects**

Comment: A friendly note that you should limit your posts to one single question as per Stack Overflow guidelines. Also, asking for opinions is discouraged so you should update your question accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: And to be fair - it was _never_ considered "good practice" to use AWS Keyspaces in place of Cassandra.  IMO, if you need Cassandra then you should use Cassandra.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to IN clause not supported in Amazon Keyspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72043450/alternative-to-in-clause-not-supported-in-amazon-keyspaces)